# Thought exercise on calculator based on adding or subtracting one within loops

Tags: java, calculator, exponent

So just as a thought exercise, I've been trying to code a very simple calculator that can perform functions such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and powers (and eventually roots) by adding or subtracting 1 through the use of for loops and nested for loops.

I need help however with the power function(last method in code below). As multiplication requires a single nested for loop (third method shown below), i figured the power function would just be another level or two deeper. But either that is not the case, or I am not coding properly, which is the more likely of the two I suppose.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Power();


}

public static void addition() {

    System.out.println("Type first number to add: ");
    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Type second number to add");
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
    int result = num1;
    while(num2 > 0){
        num2--;
        result++;
    }

    System.out.println("The result is: " + result);

}

public static void subtraction() {

    System.out.println("Type first number to subtract: ");
    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Type second number to subtract: ");
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
    int result = num1;
    while(num2 > 0){
        num2--;
        result--;
    }

    System.out.println("The result is: " + result);

}

public static void multiplication() {

    System.out.println("Type first number to multiply: ");
    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Type second number to multiply: ");
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
    int result = 0;


    for(int i = num1;i>0;i--){
        for(int x = num2;x>0;x--){
            result++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("The result is: " + result);

}

public static void division() {

    System.out.println("Type first number to divide: ");
    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Type second number to divide: ");
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
    int result = 0;

    for(;num2>0 && num1 > num2;num2--){
        result++;
        for(;num1 > num2;num1--){

        }
    }

    System.out.println("The result is: " + result);

}

public static void Power() {

System.out.println("Type Base Number: ");
int num1 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Type Exponent: ");
int num2 = scan.nextInt();
int result = 0;

for(int i = num1;i>0;i--){
    for(int x = num1;x>0;x--){
        for(int y = num2; y>0; y--){
            for(int z = num2; z>0;z--){
                result++;
            }
        }
    }

}



System.out.println("The result is: " + result);

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. This a bit more modular, but if you want it in one full loop, you can just place the code within the multiply function into the power function.

```
public int mulitply(int x, int y) {
    int product = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
          product++;
       }
    }
    return product;
}

public int power(int x, int exponent) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
        result = multiply(result, x);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Combined:

```
public int power(int x, int exponent) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {            
        int product = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < result; k++) {
                product++;
            }
        }
        result = product;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I was wondering if there is a way to do this just by using nested for loops? So far what i've discovered, based off of my current code, is that the number of nested loops need is equal to the exponent. For example, 4^4 would require 4 for loops(three of them being nested). Surely there is an easier way to do this right?

Comment: I combined it to use nested loops. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Awesome! That works perfectly. Would you mind looking at my code and explaining where I went wrong, if you can? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sure thing! Looking at your code, there are a total of 4 loops. Outer two loops are going from num1 to 0, aka num1 times for each loop, then the inner two loops are going from num2 to 0, aka num2 times for each loop, thus it is iterating through num1*num1 + num2*num2 times, which is (a^2 + b^2), which is not your desired result!